# user re-reopening duplicate question(s)

Tags: discussion

despite being told to update post and include relevant details, [he](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/48643/parth) is ignoring comments and just reopening new posts:

[Creating a fully Dynamic Table/grid in a Lightning Component [on hold]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190166/creating-a-fully-dynamic-table-grid-in-a-lightning-component)

[how do I create a lightning component where I am given 20 images and want to display them in a tabular format in a lightning component [on hold]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190188/how-do-i-create-a-lightning-component-where-i-am-given-20-images-and-want-to-dis)

[How do I create a table that will display multiple images in a single row, and can be displayed in table format such as 1x1 up to 4x5](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190225/how-do-i-create-a-table-that-will-display-multiple-images-in-a-single-row-and-c)

how does the community deal with these users? do we just ignore them and keep closing, or does someone eventually tell them to stop or be banned?

Comment: He's trying hard but he will not succeed :D

Comment: @glls I know people/users getting banned by the admins in the game Counter Strike. Do you want the same banning in the SFSE as well? lol :D :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to keep downvoting and closing poor questions. Eventually, the system will enforce a ban on the user, as described in [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997). At that point, they will be forced to either give up or fix their questions and try to garner enough good karma to be allowed to ask new questions.

Comment: Cannot they just create new user ids and keep posting? or is there a IP restriction as well?

Comment: @datasert You'll want to read the question/answers that were linked. There are filters that will block IP addresses as well. Of course, you can keep changing IP addresses, too, but eventually you're more likely to give up.

Comment: thanks. Will go through.